# About the issue in Xcode

Tags: c#, xcode, unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U38D3.png)I have some issue with Xcode of my game crash suddenly while working correctly and show Thread 1: EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY (limit=650 MB, unused=0x0) this error have you any experience with this error and how can solve it please help me it is passing second day while with this error and have tried many but not to resolve.

Comment: Can you explain what your app is doing at this point? From your stacktrace it looks like you are reading pixels from an image... can you confirm?

Comment: At this point my app crash.